# Significance testing of intercept term of random effects model, where h0 p is not 0.5

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model

Suppose subjects do a series of 3-alternative oddity trials (i.e., picking the odd-man-out from 3 samples is "success"). The null hypothesis probability of success is 1/3. I would like to know whether the subjects can pick the odd-man-out significantly more often than predicted by chance.

I *think* the way to go is to construct a random effects model:

```
model <- glmer(data,Outcome~(1|Subject),family="binomial")
summary(model)
```

...and then test whether the intercept term is different from invlogit(1/3). I can see the intercept estimate and standard error in the summary, and construct a new z score, (estimate-invlogit(1/3))/(std. err.). I have two questions:

1. Is the model I have specified the correct way to test this hypothesis?
2. Is the z score (I think this is Wald's z?) as calculated above the best way of assessing statistical significance of the intercept term? I know that for mixed models, e.g., likelihood comparison between nested models is better...can you created a nested model here where the intercept is fixed, or something?